# Ext Direct and Spring upgrade

Tags: ext-direct

I have upgraded Ext Direct from 1.3.2 to 1.8.0 and Spring Framework from 4.2.6.RELEASE to 5.1.7.RELEASE

After that actions in REMOTING_API becomes empty

```
Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {
  "url" : "/ui/.../services/router",
  "namespace" : "Ext....",
  "type" : "remoting",
  "actions" : { }
};
```

I'm stuck on this, any help will be appreciated.